# Using XFOIL to find the angle of attack corresponding to buffet onset and stall

Tags: aerodynamics, stall

I am trying to find the angle of attack that corresponds to the stall point and buffet onset. I understand for stall this occurs at the maximum lift coefficient? However upon plotting a range of angles on XFOIL it continues to ascend before it reaches a point where convergence no longer occurs so I am unsure what this means.

Comment: XFOIL uses potential code for purely subsonic flow. Per definition, it cannot be used for finding the AoA of buffet onset. Use ISES / MSES / [MISES](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/mises/mises.pdf) instead.

Comment: I may have used an incorrect term sorry- I mean like the boundary layer separation point for which the flow develops from laminar to transitional/turbulent if that makes a difference? Also, does this mean it cannot either be used to find the lift coefficient for which stall occurs? thanks

Comment: Boundary layer separation ≠ laminar to turbulent transition. Both are easy to find with XFOIL. Transition is part of regular output, separation can be found with the BL parameters output.